# Xcode 4: Archive validation fails because "app.ipa" is missing!

Tags: xcode, xcode4, app-store

During the archive validation XCode says that the archive is invalid because it misses the "app.ipa" file.
How can I get this working?

I created the archive as follows: I used for code signing the AppSore distribution profile for any iOS SDK (under the Release code signing).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with "Xcode 4 & IOS 5 beta 2". A rollback to beta 1 worked for me.